# How do you call observable that pushes values on subscribe()?

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I can't find a proper term for such thing.
So if observable pushes values when you call `subscribe()` on it,
e.g. it has `startWith()` or it's made value/list/range or it replays – how do you call it?

Comment: Are you referring to [hot and cold observables](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html)?

Comment: All observables push values (at least zero or more values) when you subscribe.

Comment: @ibebbs I don't think so. http://davesexton.com/blog/post/Hot-and-Cold-Observables.aspx replay is not strictly cold or hot, and not every cold will push value.

Comment: @Enigmativity so I'm interested in name for  "one or more")

Comment: @Pavelfljōt - What do you mean by "one or more"?

Comment: @Enigmativity one or more values being pushed immediately on `subscribe()`

Comment: @Pavelfljōt These are observables where the `onNext` call is usually made in the subscribe/create implementation. AFAIK I don't think there is such a specific term for them.

Comment: @Pavelfljōt - I don't think there's a name for "one or more" values being pushed.

Answer (score 0):

A `BehaviourSubject` (http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#BehaviorSubject) will push a value immediately on subscription. This is because it will always have one value cached ready for consumption.

An alternative is `Replay(1)` which will push a value immediately *if* the underlying sequence has ever push any value.
http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#OtherConnectables

Comment: Thank you, but this is not relevant information. Question is about terminology.

"If I subscribed to observable and it immediately pushed at least one value – this is <???> observable."

Comment: And the answer is "this is a BehaviourSubject".

Comment: Well, on rethinking, "this has BehaviourSubject semantics" is probably more accurate?